# Batch file run via shortcut changes destination folder

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch file that moves files from a specific folder to the current folder (the folder in which the command is run), but if I create a desktop link for that batch file and try running that instead, the files get moved to the folder in which the batch file resides rather than the folder in which the command is being run.  Why would this be?  Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: move M:\Logs\*.*

Comment: Try with symlink, not just simple shortcut `.lnk` file.

Comment: Are you trying to move them to the desktop?  Because otherwise, how would the batch file know where it should move them?  It is probably launching the batch file "from" it's own folder, hence copying everything there.  You may be able to fix this by changing the "start in" folder in the shortcut properties, or by explicitly listing the destination in the batch file's `move` command.

Comment: If you create a desktop shortcut to the batch file, then what folder is the batch file run from when you use the shortcut?  That is a rhetorical question meant to question your understanding of shortcuts. Did you specify in the shortcut’s properties which folder to “start in?”

Comment: I have a series of folders from which I run scripts that generate log files. The log files end up in the M:\Logs folder, but I want to move them to the specific folder I'm running the scripts from.  In Windows 7, I can run 'cmd' from the address bar in file explorer and then run the batch file to do the move and that way the move command is run from the folder I'm in, but if I try to create a desktop shortcut to that batch file, it ends up moving the log files into the same folder that the batch file is in rather than the folder I'm running from.

Comment: Thanks, Biswa.  The symbolic link idea gave me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @user2996777 please [edit] your script into the question. Comments get cleaned up and the next person will have the same question again.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to fix this.

You can change the command in your batch file to explicitly name the folder:

```
move M:\Logs\*.* C:\NewLogFolder
```

Or you can change the **Start In** location in the shortcut to the new destination:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around this is to use the "Send To" context menu.

If you "start > run" `shell:sendto`, you will get to the magic folder where send-to shortcuts are kept. You can then add a shortcut to your batch file to your desktop and then then drag the batch file shortcut into this folder (permissions may block you from adding directly).

When the batch file is run via the shortcut, the parameter `%1` will be set to the folder or file you highlighted.

So if I highlight the folder "c:\bar" and then "Sendto > Foo.bat":

foo.bat:

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
```

Would emit:

```
C:\Bar
```

If the batch file was:

```
move M:\logs\*.* %1
```

You would wind up with the proper result, so long as you do not highlight a filename. So test for errors and sanity first.